# CommaSeparatedIntegerField Implementation

Tags: django, django-models

Why is the Django Model class CommaSeparatedIntegerField implemented as text in MySQL as opposed to what it is: a list of integers?  That seems like the most inefficient thing possible!

Comment: MySQL does not support a List field. Hence the implementation

Comment: I realize they have no list field, but surely they have some binary object they could use, where the bits of each integer are stored one after the other (up to some given max length).  It seems this would be advantageous for both space and processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL (and many RDBMSes) don't have a "list" type ("lists" of items are generally separate tables associated with foreign keys). Django's `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` is a sort of hack to allow somewhat efficient storage of lists of integers, but as such it has to be stored in a string field.

(Truth be told, the field isn't commonly used in Django development anymore, but it's there if you need or want it.)